# C# WSDL Client Request Packages

Tags: c#, http, soap, wsdl, wireshark

I am currently adding a SOAP-WSDL Service to my project using "Add Service Reference". it creates all necessary classes and functions for me to call. Some of these functions dont give me a response. After 1 minute delay i get a timeout exception. However when i forge the request using Postman (a chrome extension for making network requests) it gets full response. i got suspicious and started to inspect network using Wireshark. after inspection i saw that problem was at the service. but i can't make them fix that. so i need to imitate Postman request using C#.

Main difference between mine and postman is, Postman posts all necessary data in single request for a response, but my client posts just http headers waits for a Http Continue and continues sending necessary data. i guess this breaks the service.

Here are wireshark screenshots for Postman and my client

(Postman is on the left of image and right one is my .net client - sorry for my perfect paint skills)

[image: postman vs C# client]

Is there any configuration on .net wsdl client with basicHttpBinding i can configure to make single request for a call?

edit: when i further investigated my C# client i saw that .net http layer send an initial POST with saying (Expect: 100 Continue), after it receives continue it continues to send SOAP Envelope

edit2: i changed my code to issue request using HttpWebRequest, but .net still sends header and post body with seperate requests (even when i disabled Expect: 100 Continue) and in my theory this breaks service.

question2: is there anyway to say HttpWebRequest, don't split header and body? send all of them in single request?

edit3: i solved the problem. but it wasn't about 100 Continue. service was being broken because of missing User-Agent Header

Comment: Are you setting the transport on your binding by any chance?

Comment: umm i guess i am not. i didnt think it would help with this issue. and service doesn't need any security for communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally solved the problem. after long inspections and tries i saw that remote service stops responding in the middle of the data communication if i dont add User-Agent HTTP Header. so i added http header using IClientMessageInspector before every request

here is wcf code if anybody needs it

```
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty realProp;
        object property;
        //check if this property already exists
        if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out property))
        {
            realProp = (HttpRequestMessageProperty) property;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(realProp.Headers["User-Agent"])) //don't modify if it is already set
            {
                realProp.Headers["User-Agent"] = "doktorinSM/2.1";
            }
            return null;
        }

        realProp = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        realProp.Headers["User-Agent"] = "doktorinSM/2.1";
        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, realProp);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For HttpWebRequest you can add the following to your .config file - we use this on our service. I'm not, however, sure how it impacts WCF channels.

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How so? If you add this to your client, that as one of your many edits stated was using a HttpWebRequest, it will stop your client from making two requests (I.e. the headers with "Expect: 100-continue" and then the body) and instead make a single request with all. If that's not what you're after perhaps you should make your question more clear

Comment: yeah, sorry for that. i thought problem was about 100 Continue. but later i saw that it was about missing User-Agent property. should i delete question?

Comment: and by the way, expect100Continue doesnt eliminate two request issue. it just disables 100 Continue response from server